# Escape dots from string but leave words with dots next to some keys

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match when occurs `.one` or `.zero` together with string to first dot before and any string except dot, regex like `\b(\w+)` returns any string without dot, but I need to group it like `['app', 'users.one']` or `['app', 'users.zero']` and in other cases like `['app', 'users', 'name']`, `['app', 'users']`.

```
app.users.name
app.users.one
app.users.zero
app.users
```

Comment: Try this regex: `/\.(?!(?:zero|one))/` for splitting

Comment: Or `str.match(/\w+(?:\.(?:one|zero)\b)?/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a regular expression with a [negated look-ahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead):

```
var output = input.split(/\.(?!(?:one|zero)(?:\.|$))/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead in splitting using this regex:

```
/\.(?!(?:zero|one)\b)/
```

Which will split on every DOT except when it is followed by `zero` or `one`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijrhvW/4/)

**Code:**

```
function dotsplit(str) {
   return str.split(/\.(?!(?:zero|one)\b)/);
}

arr = dotsplit('app.users.name')
//=> ["app", "users", "name"]

arr = dotsplit('app.users.one')
//=> ["app", "users.one"]

arr = dotsplit('app.users.zero')
//=> ["app", "users.zero"]

arr = dotsplit('app.users')
//=> ["app", "users"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex: `(\w+(?:\.one|\.zero)?)\b`

`(?:\.one|\.zero)` is a non-capturing group matching either `.one` or `.zero` and the question mark following it means it is optional.

Also, you don't need to put `\b` at the beginning because `\w+` will match greedily. It could however be inserted at the end to handle strings like `app.users.onetwo`.